# Computed to show the total sum of elements from an observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a data/number heavy app that I'm building with KnockoutJS. On my current screen I have a table and each cell contains a label and input. These values are being pulled from an observable array like so:

```
[
   {
      label: "some label text",
      value: 100
   }
]
```

And this is my view:

```html
<table data-bind="foreach: dosage">
    <tr>
        <td><label data-bind="text: label"></td>
        <td><input data-bind="percentage: value, number: value"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are 6 objects and I want to be able to compute the total of all the `value`s displayed in the second table column. (They all need to make a total of 100.)

I'm still getting my head around Knockout so I'm not sure what the best practice to tackle this would be?

Comment: Show your `viewModel` declaration + the HTML element that will show the total.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your example code that make it hard to directly answer your question. This includes:

- Two bindings (`percentage` and `number`) that aren't built in.
- Data (the array with just one element), but no view model code.
- You bind the `input` to "value", apparently, but without view model code it's hard to see how this would work (you need observables for two way bindings).
- No code for the root view model.

If I change up your code a bit, and make some assumptions, I get to the following:

```
var data = [
   {
      label: "some label text",
      value: 100
   }, 
   {
      label: "some label text",
      value: 100
   }
];

var ViewModel = function(dosages) {
    var self = this;
    self.dosage = ko.observableArray(dosages);
    self.totalValue = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.dosage().reduce(function(a,b) { return a.value + b.value; });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

The `value` properties are still not observable (so the input does nothing), but that's besides the point of your question, I guess.

As you can see, the above code has a `totalValue` [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) on the root view model. That's a suggestion on how you could go about creating a total.

The following markup goes with the above view model code:

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dosage">
    <tr>
        <td><label data-bind="text: label" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: totalValue" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8YZ9/) for a working demo. If you change the data object's value properties to other numbers and re-run the fiddle, you'll see a different total. If you change things up and create a *real* view model with observable properties, the two-way bindings in your `input`s will start to work too and the total will be dynamically updated.

This should get you started / answer your underlying question.

Comment: "create a real view model with observable properties, the two-way bindings in your inputs will start to work too and the total will be dynamically updated." How would I go about this? Would I have to build a static view/viewModel to allow for dynamic totals?

Comment: percentage and number are custom bindings that I've wrote. Percentage formats the underlying value to be visible with '%' and 'number' validates each input folder to allow for numbers-only.

Comment: Hmm, the question from your first comment is rather hard to answer; this (two way bindings, view models, observables) is really the basics of KO. Have you gone through the KnockoutJS tutorials on the website yet?

Comment: Yeah I've done all that, I was just wondering if there was a way to create one 'foreach' template which generates the labels and values and I can still use those values as observables?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make much sense to me. You should consider writing a follow-up SO question and elaborate quite a bit, include some sample code, etc.